# Stack in Hiding and unhiding layout in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, visibility

I'm struggling with my app. It should work like the following.

> Every time I click the button it will hide the layout **with an id of pic1** and if its already hidden it will unhide when I click the button again.

However, the problem is everytime I Click it, it goes back to the previous `Activity`.

Here the 2 layouts and a button in my layout.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/backpic"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="425dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
    android:background="@drawable/back" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/frontpic"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="425dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
    android:background="@drawable/front" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnRotate"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rotate"
    android:onClick="rotate"/>
```

If the button is clicked, it will execute the function `rotate()`.

```
public class MusclesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button btnRotate;
    LinearLayout pic1,pic2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

         btnRotate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnRotate);
         pic1 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.frontpic);
         pic2 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.backpic);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_muscles);
    }
}
```

And the function rotate is

```
public void rotate(View views) {
    if (pic1.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE)
        pic1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    else
        pic1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: show the code where rotate is called. my guess is you called rotate twice each time. you might want to put a print trace in your rotate code.

Comment: can you post the code please? It's a bit weird if it goes back to previous activity without pressing back button or having it programmatically .

Comment: where is on click code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below code once, let me know if it works.

**UPDATE**

```
public class MusclesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button btnRotate;
LinearLayout pic1,pic2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_muscles); // place it here


 btnRotate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnRotate);
 pic1 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.frontpic);
 pic2 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.backpic);
}
```

Comment: still it goes back to the previous Activity.

Comment: show your full class code, where you are handling onClick.

Comment: everything is up their.

Comment: @GabrielMamites I have updated my answer check and let me know.

Comment: thanks guys, I already solve it. I just did this

`public void rotate(View views) {

      btnRotate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnRotate);
      pic1 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.frontpic);
      pic2 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.backpic);
      
        if (pic1.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE){
            pic1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Toast.makeText(MusclesActivity.this, "VISIBLE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else
            pic1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }`

Comment: Overall, you have to set contentview first then you can use findviewbyID to use view in class level.